# Buyer specifies payment amount

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

Hi we are a property management company. Each of our clients pay different service fees each month depending on the size of their property. So the client decides the payment amount to be paid to our office. Most of the buttons on paypal need to be configured with fixed amounts. We would like to have a simple form with 'account number', 'account name' and 'amount to be paid'

Any suggestions how to approach this?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment buttons are the simplest way to access paypal. They reside in your web page so payment details do not really live there (cannot since the end user could change them). So the details like cost reside on Paypal's server and the button just contains a reference ID so that it all works. You could use payment buttons, but that would require that you create a button for each and every client and add the "code" that paypal gives you to the entry for that client.

The other option is to use the Paypal APIs. This requires that you have a web server that can use PHP or another programming language to access the APIs securely and a programmer with experience. This offers you the most flexibility payments, chained payments, store payer credit card details, etc.

The first option is an ongoing labor expense. The second is an up front expense if you need to hire someone and may require support in the future (additional cost unless you build it into the contract).

Comment: Perfect answer! Only modified it to remove 'REST' - REST API's won't necessarily be the ones he needs. I'd suggest a classic Express Checkout integration or REST-based PayPal Wallet integration (depending on OP's country with regards to product availability)

Comment: Is it not possible to have a simple form and replace the amount value in the buy button to a variable?

Comment: User, no it isn't possible to do that because the price with a button is stored on Paypal's servers. If it were possible to change it like that, I'd be able to use a buy now button to get a discount (or free) on a buy now button where the seller didn't intend. @Robert, I was pretty sure the new location of the docs said classic was going away (no sunset date).